# How to overwrite file while using tFileOutputDelimited in TOS

Tags: etl, talend

In TOS, i am getting the below error

```
    Exception in component tFileOutputDelimited_1 (First_Practice_Job)
java.lang.RuntimeException: The particular file "C:\Users\himanshu\Desktop\tos\written_file.csv" already exist. If you want to overwrite the file, please uncheck the "Throw an error if the file already exist" option in Advanced settings.
    at my_first_project.first_practice_job_0_1.First_Practice_Job.tFileInputDelimited_2Process(First_Practice_Job.java:2162)
    at my_first_project.first_practice_job_0_1.First_Practice_Job.runJobInTOS(First_Practice_Job.java:2694)
    at my_first_project.first_practice_job_0_1.First_Practice_Job.main(First_Practice_Job.java:2543)
```

As guided in this error, the option for unchecking is not available in advance settings,
So while using tFileOutputDelimited, how to overwrite file instead of deleting and then running the program again and again

Answer (score 2):

The option disappears if you have checked "write after" in the simple parameters. Otherwise it should be available in advanced parameters

[image: French interface, but option is present]

I am not using TOS, but Talend Cloud Api for Services 7.2.1 . Don't have a TOS to double check this

Comment: I have not checked "write after", if the option for overwrite appears in your TOS, could you share screenshot of it please?